# Отправка нескольких медиа произвольного количества и типа одним сообщением TelegramBot Java

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telegrambots

Мне нужно, чтобы мой тг-бот отправлял сообщение с несколькими медиафайлами и текстом.
**Однако**:

- Количество файлов меняется от сообщения к сообщению и неизвестно заранее (минимум 1, максимум 10)
- В одном сообщении могут комбинироваться разные типы файлов (картинки, видео, гифки)

Я пытаюсь использовать метод `SendMediaGroup()`, однако он не принимает списки в качестве параметра. У меня получилось только захардкодить параметры заранее известными значениями.

Получается код вида:

```
telegramBot.execute(new SendMediaGroup(chatID,
            fileURL0.caption(text),
            fileURL1,   
            ... 

            fileURL9));
```

**Вопрос**: как избежать хардкода и передавать во второй параметр `SendMediaGroup()` контейнер с несколькими объектами?

Использую библиотеку:

```
com.github.pengrad:java-telegram-bot-api:6.2.0
```

Comment: Использую библиотеку pengrad-telegramBot 6.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конструктор класса `SendMediaGroup` принимает на вход [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html) из объектов `InputMedia`.

Varargs в Java преобразуется в обычный массив на стадии компиляции. Чтобы передать список в varargs, его нужно преобразовать в массив:

```java
List<InputMedia<?>> mediaList = ...;
InputMedia<?>[] mediaArray = mediaList.toArray(InputMedia[]::new);
telegramBot.execute(new SendMediaGroup(chatId, mediaArray));
```

Если у вас версия Java ниже 1.8, то используйте `new InputMedia[0]` вместо `InputMedia[]::new` для создания нового массива.

Comment: Ого. Я читал про массив из параметров, но не мог правильно сконвертировать список в подходящий массив. Теперь все работает. Спасибо!